# How do I edit a post on Facebook either through the app or through a browser from an S3?

Tags: facebook

I know you can edit a status post if it has a picture in it on the desktop but when I try to do the same thing through a browser on my S3 or through the app it doesn't work.  Any tips on the problem?

OS: 4.1.1
S3

Comment: Sounds more like a Facebook issue rather than an Android related one. Anyway, did you try accessing the **desktop** version of the page from your phone's browser?

Comment: Yes, I have but it's something sbout the Android OS though or the touchscreen because it works on PC.